# Ubuntu 18.04 brightness/backlight command

Tags: 18.04, gnome, brightness, backlight

In Ubuntu 18.04 with GNOME, what is the command that is used to change the display brightness (backlight)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these commands in most if not all versions of gnome:

```bash
# Increase brightness:
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power --object-path /org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Power --method org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.Screen.StepUp

# Decrease brightness:
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power --object-path /org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Power --method org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.Screen.StepDown
```

If you have multiple monitors, you may be interested in [this script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1155093/turn-off-all-monitors-while-watching-vlc-media-on-tv/1155095#1155095) which dims up to three monitors after 5 minutes of inactivity until mouse is moved or key is pressed. This is convenient when watching a movie on a second to fourth monitor (ie Big Screen TV).

At the very least the script will help you learn `xrandr` in general and how to change brightness using `xrandr` in great detail.

Comment: Thank you! These commands are exactly what I was looking for. And thanks for the script, might come handy some time.

Answer (score 2):

xrandr can do this. Type in xrandr to find the name of the display that's connected it will likely be named whatever_interface_you_use-1. Then use

```
xrandr --output the_display_name --brightness brightness_level
```

With brightness-level being a number between 0 and 1. Don't type in 0 unless you want your screen to go black.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The `xrandr` command corerctly changes the brightness, however what I meant by "brightness" was more like the display backlight. I should have stated that more clearly.