# Controlling keyboard backlight based on idle time

Tags: scripts, idle

On a tablet running 19.04, the keyboard backlight automatically turns off after a period of inactivity. I'd like to have that same function on my desktop.

The following script allows me to manually control the backlight:

```
xset led on
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard mousekeys-enable true
sleep 1
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard mousekeys-enable false
```

This turns the backlight on, then due to a bug with Ubuntu caused by running the `xset` command, I have to enable, then disable Mouse Keys to prevent the numpad from running as a mouse emulator. An identical script would need to be run to turn the backlight off, with the only difference being `xset led off`.

What I'd like to do is to take this script, and have it run after a certain period of inactivity. Is there an existing function running in the background that I could add such a script so? If not, what would be the simplest way to create something that achieves the desired results?

Comment: You could take this script which slowly dims two out of three monitors and gut most of it. I can do that later as well: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1155093/turn-off-all-monitors-while-watching-vlc-media-on-tv

Comment: I've come across others suggesting using xprintidle as well. Out of curiosity, is there a way to do this without installing additional packages?

Comment: Don't think of xprintidle as a real extra package. It's just a tiny functional enhancement to Xorg IMO.