# Turn off primary screen, Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: keyboard, multiple-monitors

I usually run two monitors. Sometimes I'd like to turn off only the primary (laptop) screen. My old Asus laptop had an fn key for this until recently (I don't know why, but it started putting the laptop to sleep instead).

I could do this by changing to external screen only. However not only this resets the joint screen setting but also moves all the laptop apps to the external screen.

Any ideas? Ideally I'd have this macro called from one of the fn keys (current laptop has 3 "empty" ones).

Answer (score 2):

As demonstrated by this script you can turn off laptop screen:

- [Turn off all monitors while watching VLC media on TV](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1155093/turn-off-all-monitors-while-watching-vlc-media-on-tv/1155095#1155095)

To discover the power setting for your laptop display use:

```bash
$ ls /sys/class/backlight/*/bl_power

/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/bl_power
```

On my laptop the driver name is `intel_backlight`

Move your terminal window to your external screen and turn off your laptop display with:

```bash
echo 4 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/bl_power
```

or a shorter version without specifying the name should work for all laptops:

```bash
echo 4 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/*/bl_power
```

To turn the screen back on:

```bash
echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/*/bl_power
```

---

You can also get a list of your monitors for `xrandr` software control:

```bash
$ xrandr | grep " connected"
HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1107mm x 623mm
eDP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+3840+2160 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 382mm x 215mm
DP-1-1 connected 3840x2160+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1600mm x 900mm
```

`xrandr` allows you to turn off a screen but then all windows will move to the screen that is left turned on which is what you don't want.