# Monitor computer use time

Tags: gnome

I would like to monitor the time I spend using my computer. The time spent on each program would be a nice plus, but not necessary. Uptime would not be sufficient since the computer I may leave the computer on. I am guessing there is some app to do this, but I would also be ok with a more bottom up solution (e.g., monitoring activity from user inputs or X11 to determine if the computer is being used and then keeping a log).

Comment: Possible answer: https://github.com/ActivityWatch/activitywatch

Comment: new tweak    https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3556/time-awareness/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this answer doesn't do everything you want but they are bash scripts you could modify.

First solution would be to have your machine automatically suspend when inactive. Then this [script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/321855/how-to-get-real-uptime) can be used:

```
$ suspendtime
Nov 10 13:51:52 to Nov 10 18:43:27 suspended 4 hours, 51 minutes, 35 seconds
Nov 11 00:33:26 to Nov 11 07:48:14 suspended 7 hours, 14 minutes, 48 seconds
Nov 11 13:23:28 to Nov 11 18:30:26 suspended 5 hours, 6 minutes, 58 seconds
Nov 11 21:48:00 to Nov 12 04:24:46 suspended 6 hours, 36 minutes, 46 seconds
Nov 12 05:51:51 to Nov 12 17:43:22 suspended 11 hours, 51 minutes, 31 seconds
Nov 12 21:51:33 to Nov 13 04:21:19 suspended 6 hours, 29 minutes, 46 seconds
Nov 13 05:54:53 to Nov 13 18:55:32 suspended 13 hours, 39 seconds
Nov 13 20:27:03 to Nov 13 23:11:23 suspended 2 hours, 44 minutes, 20 seconds
Nov 14 00:46:49 to Nov 14 07:27:29 suspended 6 hours, 40 minutes, 40 seconds
Nov 14 13:20:49 to Nov 14 18:56:52 suspended 5 hours, 36 minutes, 3 seconds
Nov 15 00:16:33 to Nov 15 07:33:53 suspended 7 hours, 17 minutes, 20 seconds
Nov 15 13:06:38 to Nov 15 18:07:34 suspended 5 hours, 56 seconds
Nov 15 21:46:09 to Nov 16 04:20:41 suspended 6 hours, 34 minutes, 32 seconds
Nov 16 05:55:28 to Nov 16 18:13:27 suspended 12 hours, 17 minutes, 59 seconds
Nov 16 21:36:22 to Nov 17 04:07:29 suspended 6 hours, 31 minutes, 7 seconds

Linux uptime 582,903 seconds ( 6 days, 17 hours, 55 minutes, 3 seconds)
15 Suspends 388,500 seconds ( 4 days, 11 hours, 55 minutes)
Real uptime 194,403 seconds ( 2 days, 6 hours, 3 seconds)
```

---

The second solution is close to your needs but has no logging. When you are watching movies this [script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1155093/turn-off-all-monitors-while-watching-vlc-media-on-tv/1155095#1155095) dims the other two monitors and records inactivity time in X11:

[image: movie.sh status display.png]